# How to remove unwanted numbers from the navbar-collapse [ASP.NET webform]

Tags: html, css, asp.net, webforms, navbar

[image: unwanted numbers in nav_bar collapse]

I have been struggling to remove the numbers `1` in the background of the `nav-bar collapse` and i have attached a picture for a better visualization of this weird phenomenon for which i do not have the slightest idea about its origin.

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a runat="server" href="~/">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a runat="server" href="~/About">About</a></li>
                    <li><a runat="server" href="~/Team">Team</a></li>
                    <li><a runat="server" href="~/Resources">Resources</a></li>
                    <li><a runat="server" href="~/Contact">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
```

As a corollary (maybe), a picture in the center of the page is hitting (see image in blue) the `height` of the `navbar-collapse` although from the `design mode`, the image is well centered without hitting anything.

Feedback about this phenomenon would highly be appreciated.

Comment: I can drop that code right in and not see any 1's at all.  Is there any other HTML outside that div (still inside the <nav> blocks) that might be playing with it?

Comment: yes some basic `<script>` without any particular incidence. very stange.

Comment: The `1` is not coming from that HTML. But it may be coming from a stylesheet or a script on your site. Therefore it is necessary to have a link to your site to troubleshoot.

Comment: Yes, post the link so we can inspect the source.  It might provide more insight.  But you can always click F12 and check the browser debugger.  Identify the element where the 1's are occurring and start unchecking styles.  That will help you know if it's a styling issue.  If not, then you will need to see what other scripts are running that are modifying HTML.

Comment: @MistaPrime and JohnPete : thanks for your feedback. `<style>` and `<bootstrap.css>` are causing a bit of versatility in the site. Thus, you may be right although it would be a 'needle in a haystack' as the code becomes huge (:). Cheers